# Assigning dictionary to a class object

Tags: python, python-class

What is the difference between the two class definitions below,

```py
class my_dict1(dict):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self = data.copy()
        self.N = sum(self.values)
```

The above code results in `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'N'`, while the below code compiles

```py
class my_dict2(dict):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for k, v in data.items():
             self[k] = v
        self.N = sum(self.values)
```

For example,

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 5}
a = my_dict1(d) # results in attribute error
b = my_dict2(d) # works fine
```

Comment: Note, `self = whatever` is *probably not doing what you think it is doing*. `self` is just a local variable in the `__init__` function, it's not magic, and won't change your instance. So you are just assigning the `dict` you passed in to a local variable, `self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning `self` itself to anything you assign `self` to a completely different instance than you were originally dealing with, making it no longer the "self". This instance will be of the broader type `dict` (because `data` is a `dict`), not of the narrower type `my_dict1`. You would need to do `self["N"]` in the first example for it to be interpreted without error, but note that even with this, in something like:

```
abc = mydict_1({})
```

`abc` will still not have the key "N" because a completely difference instance in `__init__` was given a value for the key "N". This shows you that there's no reasonable scenario where you want to assign `self` itself to something else.

In regards to `my_dict2`, prefer composition over inheritance if you want to use a particular `dict` as a representation of your domain. This means having `data` as an instance field. See the related C# question [Why not inherit from List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt), the core answer is still the same. It comes down to whether you want to extend the `dict` mechanism vs. having a business object based on it.

Comment: Consider clarifying the difference between the local variable `self` and the object that was originally referenced by `self`. This answer could mislead someone into believing that `my_dict1.__init__` somehow swaps the original `my_dict1` instance with a `dict`, which is not the case.

Comment: To clarify (inside class `__init__`), `self = data` is assigning to local variable, while `self[k] = data[k]` assigns to `self` object?